# Appending into a list

Tags: python, list, append

```
def silly(n):
    """requires: n is an int > 0
    Gets n inputs from user
    Prints 'Yes' if the inputs are a palindrome; 'No' otherwise"""
    assert type(n) == int and n > 0
    for i in range(n):
        result= []
        elem = input('Enter something: ')
        result.append(elem)
        print(result)

    if isPal(result):
        print('Is a palindrome')
    else:
        print('Is not a palindrome')
```

If you try running this function, with for example, as n = 3, why doesn't the elem append to the result properly? It keeps printing as new list of results. This messages up my isPal function.

Answer (score 2):

The first line of your for loop replaces your `result` variable with a new list.

```
result= []
```

You should do this before the for loop instead.

Comment: No problem - if that solved your issue, don't forget to tick this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Swap these lines:

```
result = []
for i in range(n):
    # ...
```

Or you will be reassigning `result` in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are redefining result each time.

```
def silly(n):
    """requires: n is an int > 0
    Gets n inputs from user
    Prints 'Yes' if the inputs are a palindrome; 'No' otherwise"""
    assert type(n) == int and n > 0
    result= []
    for i in range(n):
        elem = input('Enter something: ')
        result.append(elem)
    print(result)
```